# I can't add a column throught a r script in power bi

Tags: r, powerbi

I would like to add a new column throught a r script but appears the next error:

[image]

The r code works like I want if I run it in R-Studio but in Power BI doesn't.

Here the r code:

```
library(stats)
library(base)

dataset$llam_acum = 0

for (i in 1: nrow(dataset)) 

{

  if (i < 5)

    {

      dataset$llam_acum[i] = dataset$`Llamadas acumuladas`[i]

    }

  else

    {

        if (dataset$Fecha[i] == dataset$Fecha[i-4]) 

          {

            dataset$llam_acum[i] = dataset$`Llamadas acumuladas`[i]-dataset$`Llamadas acumuladas`[i-4]

          }

        else

          {

            dataset$llam_acum[i] = dataset$`Llamadas acumuladas`[i]

          }
      }
}
```

And here a extract of the database:

```
Type    Llamadas acumuladas Fecha
A   24  06/02/2020
B   1   06/02/2020
C   67  06/02/2020
D   25  06/02/2020
A   94  06/02/2020
B   4   06/02/2020
C   241 06/02/2020
D   122 06/02/2020
A   188 06/02/2020
B   8   06/02/2020
C   482 06/02/2020
D   243 06/02/2020
A   237 06/02/2020
B   10  06/02/2020
C   629 06/02/2020
D   332 06/02/2020
A   305 06/02/2020
B   12  06/02/2020
C   856 06/02/2020
D   441 06/02/2020
A   362 06/02/2020
B   17  06/02/2020
C   1002    06/02/2020
D   518 06/02/2020
A   418 06/02/2020
B   18  06/02/2020
C   1134    06/02/2020
D   600 06/02/2020
A   537 06/02/2020
B   23  06/02/2020
C   1445    06/02/2020
D   745 06/02/2020
A   566 06/02/2020
B   27  06/02/2020
C   1544    06/02/2020
D   787 06/02/2020
A   636 06/02/2020
B   27  06/02/2020
C   1699    06/02/2020
D   884 06/02/2020
```

Why this error apears?

I'm using R 3.6.2 and power bi 2.65.5313.841 64 bit (dec 18)

thanks for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dataset name. Please also note that I have changed the column name "Llamadas acumuladas" to "Llamadas". To give you an example, this script works for me:

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset_out <- dataset %>% group_by(Type) %>% mutate(llamadas_accum = cumsum(Llamadas))
```